# MySQL encoding issue (ç,İ,ö)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Not working special characters. Like (ç,İ,ö)

For Example:

> Text: I love çulets
>   Output: Ilove%C3%A7ulets

```html
$D->query = '';
 
 if ($this->param('t')) {
  $D->query = mb_convert_encoding($this->param('t'), 'UTF-8');
   //$D->query = htmlspecialchars($this->param('t'));
 }
```

Comment: That's how it works, it takes something and 'encodes' it to a numeric format.  When you want to display it you need something like `html_entity_decode`

Comment: Your parameter was either double-URI-encoded or not properly decoded in the first place. Was this sent over JSON? It's frequently the case that client-side apps mistakenly URI-encode properties in a JSON document, which is a bug.

Comment: Sent from php file to mysql.

Comment: @Forbs, how can i do that ?

Comment: @Forbs Those aren't HTML entities, that is URL encoded.

Comment: How is `t` being sent?

Comment: @chris85 /search/t:Iloveçulets

Comment: What does `param(` do? Does `$_GET['t']` have `Iloveçulets`? `$_GET` is auto decoded so you might need to add that to the `param` function, or use the decoding there... or it might be double encoded as already stated.

Comment: Issue meanwhile in query. You're saying about URL ? or i don't know, sorry about that.